# State of PPA's after a distribution upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, ppa

Suppose a hypothetical situation where I am upgrading from one version of Ubuntu to the next (e.g. 18.10 to 19.04, but can be any pair of adjacent versions), and I've got a lot of third-party repositories from which I download packages. Upon upgrading to the next distribution version, what happens to said repositories? Do they get updated, too, if available, or do they just stay on the previous version?

For example, suppose I have this repository in my `sources.list` or `sources.list.d`

```
deb https://something.org/stuff/foo/ cosmic main
```

and one for Disco Dingo exists (but is not [yet] added because it's in the next version)

```
deb https://something.org/stuff/foo/ disco main
```

Would I have to update my PPA's manually like this, or is this automatic?

Answer (score 0):

First, recall that PPAs are NOT official, supported sources for Ubuntu software. Some projects (mis)use PPAs to distribute unofficial packages - your support for those packages comes from that project, not us. Ubuntu conducts no quality assurance or checking of any kind on most PPA packages. We have no idea if they are laden with malware or not. Use entirely at your own risk.

Second, recall that lots of terrible or ancient instructions on the internet tell folks to install PPAs quite needlessly. In many cases, the software is in the Ubuntu repositories already, or in Ubuntu's Snap Store.

Since PPAs are published by random folks across the internet, Ubuntu cannot compel them to adhere to the release schedule. **Packages for a new release may appear on time, or many months later, or never.** This is one reason that PPAs are automatically disabled during a release-upgrade.

You must update PPAs manually after a release upgrade.

**Best practice for a trouble-free release-upgrade with PPAs:**

1) Prepare: Uninstall all PPA packages and disable all PPA sources. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible. The `ppa-purge` tool makes this step very easy.

2) Preparation: Update/upgrade your system to ensure your old release is up-to-date.

3) Do the release-upgrade

4) Check your list of PPAs and other Non-Ubuntu software to determine which are no longer needed. (e.g.: Don't use it anymore, the feature is now in Ubuntu, use the new Snap instead, etc.) Delete these PPAs from your list.

5) Check your list of PPAs to determine which don't have packages compatible with your new release of Ubuntu. Generally, it is a Very Bad Idea to try to install wrong-release packages. Doing so can break your system quite horribly. Revisit these PPAs in a few months to see if the new release is supported.

6) Edit and re-add the PPAs that you want to keep, and that have compatible packages for your new release. Re-add each PPA one at a time, including separate update/upgrades for each PPA. Watch your apt output carefully for errors and warnings.